# heat of a laptop when placed on a table, when placed on a pile of books and when placed on a bed

Tags: heat, everyday-life

I heard somewhere that it is dangerous to place a laptop on a bed. The reason given was that placing the laptop on the bed blocks (assume that the laptop does not have sideway fans - it only has air holes or air intake fans at the bottom.) the air intake fans of the laptop. However, we often place our laptops on a table or desk.
So, what makes the laptop to over-heat when placed on a bed?

Also, If one places a laptop on a pile of books, will the laptop over-heat?

Answer (score 1):

If you place it on a flat hard surface like a desk, the feet on the bottom lift it up slightly so that the air vent on the bottom is clear.
If you put it on a bed the air vent will be covered by the soft material and so might over heat.

Comment: Maybe conductivity of the material is a minor side issue